# Python - f.out filename

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, so please bear with me if I am asking a very silly question. I have looked around but probably me not understanding how to fix this.

I am running a script to read a CSV file, find and replace values and then write to a file. CSV file contains 'n' number of rows and for each row a different file needs to be created, appended by the value in "row 3", with the values replaced. However when I run the script, I only get one output file which is for the last row. Below is my script.

```
file_reader= open('variables.csv', "rt")
read = csv.reader(file_reader)

for row in read:
     values = { '[type]':row[0], '[model]':row[1], '[name]':row[2],'[host]':row[3] } 



if row[0] == "1": 
    if row[1] == "alpha":
        t = open("alpha.conf", "r")
    elif row[1] == "beta":
        t = open("beta.conf", "r")

def replace_words(base_text, device_values):

temp = t.read()
t.close()

output = replace_words(temp, values)

outputfile = "host"+row[3]+".txt"
fout = open(outputfile,'w')
fout.write(output)
fout.close()
```

Please can someone help and advise what I am doing wrong here.

thanks,

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: Your code's indentation is _still_ messed-up because you're using tabs instead of spaces to do it.

Comment: thanks, will attempt to correct these.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts in this code:

```
for row in read:
  values = {
    '[type]': row[0],
    '[model]': row[1],
    '[name]': row[2],
    '[host]': row[3] }
```

You do the assignment for each row but you assign all the nice dictionaries you create to the same variable `values`.  Of course only the last row will be in `values` in the end.

You can create a list of values using a list comprehension:

```
values = [ { '[type]': row[0],
             '[model]': row[1],
             '[name]': row[2],
             '[host]': row[3] } for row in read ]
```

This will not fix everything (for understanding more we need you to fix the indentation first, in order to understand what you could be trying), but it might be a start.

Comment: Thanks Alfe, will give that a try and post back what I get.